# How to delete all parent references of a taxonomy term?

Tags: 8

How to delete references to parent terms?

I tried this:

```
$term->get('parent')->setValue(NULL);
$term->save();
```

Additional question: how to delete reference to a specific parent term?

Answer (score 3):

Answering to myself. Taxonomy hierarchy is known to be *detached* from terms. For example when loading term you don't get its parents. This was confusing to me and I thought `setValue()` just doesn't work. But the truth is that it works perfectly.

To get the code from above working, only a minor edit is required - it's using `0`, not `NULL`:

```
$term->get('parent')->setValue(0);
```

This **deletes all the hierarchy the term has** and writes one record to the `taxonomy_term_hierarchy` table - with zero parent.

If you need to delete the hierarchy manually you can use `deleteTermHierarchy()`:

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term');->deleteTermHierarchy($tid);
```

but be warned that the term will disappear from the lists on `/admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/<vocabulary>/overview` page since it's missing any hierarchy now. To *fix* this you need to add a record to the `taxonomy_term_hierarchy` table with zero parent. And that's exactly what `setValue(0)` does - deletes hierarchy and adds that record.